# Is it possible to use Vuetify without Vue?

Tags: vuetify.js

On my site I have +10 pages.
One of them uses Vue and Vuetify and it works well together with Vue when I do something like this:

```
new Vue({
            el: '#navbar',
            vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

But on other pages. I only need, lets say some input-fields, because I am using .net core MVC to handle it. Is it possible to use certain classes on Inputs (similar to Bootstrap)?

I have found out that the Grid-system works.

- The inputs dont work
- Even "text-center"-class dont work if the parent does not have the correct class

So I would love to have something like this:
`<input type="text" class="here-is-the-classes-i-need">`
So I guess my question is.

Could I use Vuetify in a similar way as bootstrap? Or do I need to add Bootstrap too?

*I am afraid that will be much to load for the user?!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't run Vuetify without Vue.

The reason is pretty simple, most of Vuetify is built with vue and most of those components require their script to run, so everything that's not entirely css based will not work.

But at the end of the day, that's fine. Once compiled, if you've imported Vuetify's components manually (and not the whole lib at once), the bundle size shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: Then I will consider use Foundation on the rest of the page. And Vuetify on the single page I have my Vue....How does that sound?

Comment: It really depends on how your website is built and your architecture. If Vuetify's assets are already cached, I'd probably stick with it, as the user wouldn't have to reload everything. Reimporting a whole new framework on top of the other seems like a bad plan

Answer (score 1):

You can't vuetify with vue. But if you need you can use vue in any isolated part of an application.

Suppose that you have a page where you need to use data-table from vuetify and the rest all on the page is from any other x-framework, you can do that.

Just import vue and vuetify directly to the head section of the HTML and mount the app.

```
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.0/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuex@3.2.0/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.0/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</head>
    
<div id="app">
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</div>
<script>
  const myueApp = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
           text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          // You know what else is going to come here, I am skipping to make the answer clean, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables
        ]
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

You can use all the vue api's in the app myVueApp . And the best part is that you can even access functions and data from outside the vueApp. to do that just use
const temp = myVueApp.desserts;

Comment: Yes, but lets say I need it for a small login. WIth username, password and a button. is it not bad practice to just make a standalone for that little code? Or should I just do that...I guess it will solve all my problems..

Comment: I just need a components that goes well with Vue (slider and multiselect), navbar (preferable work without vue), other inputs (work with and without vue-code). Maybe I am  the only one having this problem?

Comment: Anything that solves your issues when there is no other solution is not a "bad practice". In fact, the main selling point of vue is that it can be added to an isolated part of an application while all the other part of the same application is working on a different framework.

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify uses Google's 'Material Design', which you can use separately:

https://m2.material.io/components?platform=web

The documentation is perhaps a little less friendly compared to Vuetify's though - and the set of 'components' is a bit thinner.